# How do I read each word and store it to a variable to use?

Tags: ada

I'm new to Ada. Syntax is throws me off. I have 6 years in Java and it's similar to this what we do in java but I quite can't get it working. I'm studying using learn.adacore.com.

```
with Ada.Text_IO; Use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO; use Ada.Float_Text_IO;

procedure TextFile is

   F      : File_Type;
   File_Name : constant String := "Store.txt";
begin
   
   Open (F, In_File, File_Name);
   
   while not End_Of_File (F) loop
      Put_Line (Get_Line (F));
   end loop;
   Close (F);
   
end TextFile;
```

This is my text file called Store.txt

```
Code    Department  Name/Vendor  Title          ID      Payrate
IL      Sales       John         Sales_person   1378    25.46
```

Comment: I don't know if this might help, but try specifying what package your Get_Line or Put_Line  are from. E.g. with Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line (F) or  Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get_Line (F)

Comment: Maybe it's your poor English, but I don't understand what you're asking. Your title is about reading words (an undefined concept), but your code only reads lines. You say it doesn't work, but your code compiles fine (with warnings that Ada.Integer_Text_IO and Ada.Float_Text_IO are not used).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind portability between different Ada compilers, you can use package GNAT.String_Split to split the whole line as array of separated String values:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;       use Ada.Text_IO;
with GNAT.String_Split; use GNAT.String_Split;

procedure TextFile is
   File   : File_Type;
   Tokens : Slice_Set;
begin
   Open (File, In_File, "Store.txt");
   -- Skip the file header
   Skip_Line (File);
   -- Read the data
   while not End_Of_File (File) loop
      -- Split the line from the file on array which contains separated
      -- words. Treat multiple spaces as a single separator (don't
      -- create empty elements).
      Create (Tokens, Get_Line (File), " ", Multiple);
      -- Print each of the array's values
      for I in 1 .. Slice_Count (Tokens) loop
         Put_Line (Slice (Tokens, I));
      end loop;
   end loop;
   Close (File);
end TextFile;
```